# nodejs express login fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I am using express session to login user.

### Middleware:

```
var requireLogin = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.session.user) {
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/'); 
    }
}
```

### Route:

```
app.post('/login', requireLogin, routes.login);

exports.login = function (req, res) {
    var query = {username:req.body.username, password:req.body.password};

    User.find(query, function (err, data) {
        if (data) {
            req.session.user = data;
            console.log(data);
            res.redirect('/home');
        } else {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
};
```

When I enter a wrong username and password, it still redirect to home, but the data is `null`.

Comment: This is weird, try checking data && data.login for example.

Comment: the console.log(data) shows [],so i try to use data.length as the condition and it works, but why? it seems User.find() returns a empty array

Comment: That is normal paste this in a node shell `if([]){console.log ("yeah")};`

Comment: That's what you would expect User.find to return if the query executed without error but there were no matching rows. Finding no rows is not an error, it's just an empty result set. An error is something like asking for a column/key that doesn't exist or losing the connection to the data store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns an array of match results and `findOne` returns a matching document.

I guess `findOne` is appropriate for this case.

```
app.post('/login', requireLogin, routes.login);

exports.login = function (req, res) {
    var query = {username:req.body.username, password:req.body.password}; 
    User.findOne(query, function (err, data) {
        if (data && !err) {
            req.session.user = data;
            console.log(data);
            res.redirect('/home');
        } else {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `find` returns an array of results, `if (data)` will still evaluate to `true` even if it's empty.

`findOne` would be more appropriate, because you are looking for just the one user with that unique username/password combination. This way `if (data)` will only evaluate to `true` if a matching `User` if found.

```
User.findOne(query, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {   
        // the username/password could be valid (or not), 
        // but there's no way to tell because there was some server error
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect('/');
    } else if (data) {
        // a user was found that matched the query
        req.session.user = data;
        console.log(data);
        res.redirect('/home');
    } else { 
        // there is no User that matches the query
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```